# How Use Count and Like Clause Together in MySql Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have used below stored procedure that dynamically get table name and also get search keyword.

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTableLength`(IN TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
                                                                           IN SEARCH VARCHAR(150)) BEGIN IF (SEARCH = '') THEN
SET @query = CONCAT('select count(*) as total from ',TABLE_NAME); ELSE
SET @query = CONCAT('select count(userId) as total from ',TABLE_NAME, ' WHERE userName like ', SEARCH); END IF; PREPARE stmt3
FROM @query; EXECUTE stm3; END
```

when i call above procedure like below.

```
   CALL GetTableLength('usertbl', 'kisan')
```

Here, kisan is a search keyword.

Then following error occured. what's wrong?

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'kisan' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like below:

```
set @query = CONCAT("select count(userId) as total from ",table_name, " WHERE userName like '", search,"'");
```

Even you can try like :

```
set @query = CONCAT("select count(userId) as total from ",table_name, " WHERE userName like '%", search,"%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass search parameter in like statement with quote `''`